# Encountering "TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php" error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, csrf

I am attempting to perform an AJAX submission to Laravel. According to Laravel's documentation [here](https://github.com/barryvdh/docs/blob/dfce193f3c70368b71ac9c2f3cfefd585687aa1f/routing.md#insert-the-csrf-token-into-a-form), I need to add a CSRF token as both a request header and POST parameter. I'm retrieving the CSRF Token from the `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie as also described in the documentation:

```
// Grab XSRF cookie.
var csrf_token;
var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
for(cookie_offset in cookies) {
    var cookie_parts = cookies[cookie_offset].split('=');
    if(cookie_parts[0].trim() === 'XSRF-TOKEN') {
        csrf_token = cookie_parts[1].trim();
    }
}
```

This retrieves a token similar to the following:
`eyJpdiI6Ik96QTdtcFIzam85TGJNQ3pzNUF1blE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiQm8zelBSaFpaM0JZcjlxcURFVEZNenZWMzNxUHFBMm1VVzM3YXpBbjVvaTBReEY5cFA1RGV3UVBHQWhjVGhZYmtDZ2lacGxFejJwQkxHaGplV1wvVEtRPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI3NTlkZmI5ODU2YTdlN2RiYTA1YTAyM2NiZmZlOWUwZTQyY2I0NTUzOWEyNzI5YjE2ODIyMmU1YzZiNDE1MmQ0In0`

Once I have the token, I am adding it as a `X-CSRF-Token` header and `_token` POST parameter.

When I perform the request, I'm receiving this error:
`TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46`

I've also tried passing the token as a `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header instead, but am getting the same error

When I set the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` and omit the `_token` POST parameter, I encounter a different error:
`DecryptException in Encrypter.php line 142:
Invalid data.`

What is it that I am missing here?

**UPDATE**:
After some more debugging and comparing this request with requests being generated by an AngularJS implementation which ran side-by-side this implementation, I discovered the problem was that I needed to URL Decode the cookie's value.

I simply needed to do the following, after extracting the csrf token from the cookies:

`csrf_token = decodeURIComponent(csrf_token );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the token to the client's request either for AJAX or as a hidden field in a form.  You have to add a way for the client to know what the token is.  One method is to use the token meta tag from the base view:

```
<meta name="xsrf-token" content="{{Session::token()}}" />
```

Then in your javascript side for any ajax request you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajaxSetup({
     headers: {
       'X-CSRF-Token':$('meta[name="xsrf-token"]).attr('content')
     }
  });
}
```

Otherwise when you post you can use the CSRF token in a hidden field
as so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
```

Comment: Doesn't grabbing the token from the cookie solve this?

Comment: How are you submitting your request.  If it is a form then you need the _token hidden field.  If it is through ajax then the header is fine.  Although if I am not mistaken they are not the same values.  The cookie has a different value that can be matched up.

Comment: I am attempting to perform an AJAX submission, using jquery. I'll try omitting the _token form field as I'm already using the header.

Comment: Documentation says you can use the cookie value but you send X-XSRF-TOKEN instead of X-CSRF-TOKEN

Comment: I updated my question to include only X-XSRF-TOKEN header error being thrown

Comment: Did you set up the encryption token in the config folder?

Comment: CSRF tokens automatically inserted via Laravel's templating system works fine, so I don't think it's an encryption configuration issue.